# Java multi-thread switching context vs submit new task and solution for monitoring a queue

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

- About switching context (synchronizing with wait/notify) between threads and re-submit a task (Callable/Runnable) to Executor service which is better for performance? as I know switching context need to save/reload thread data but if I re-submit a task to an Executor service, JVM need to re-allocate stack for the submitted task so I think it has same cost with switching context?
- I design a task queue for worker threads put tasks to that and a monitor thread to take the tasks in the queue, submit the tasks to a thread pool (executor service). But I considering about when does the monitor thread work?
  Option 1: Using thread "wait" for monitor thread and worker thread will notify the monitor thread after they put task to the queue.
  Option 2: Using a scheduler executor service for monitor thread  to check the queue.
  -> Which option is better (for speed, performance) and with option 2: how often  to check the queue is the best?

many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

1. An executor is usually backed by a thread pool. So the stacks are already allocated. Furthermore, a context switch will only take place if the *same* CPU core has to execute both threads. Modern CPUs have multiple cores, so there would be no context switch involved.

   Having said that, there is surely *some* overhead in transferring work to another thread. So tasks should be sufficiently coarse-grained and there should be other work that the main thread can perform in the meantime for the pool to be beneficial.
2. There is no need to have a monitor thread if the queue itself is synchronized. Have a look at [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) for example; producers can call the `put()` method (which blocks when no space in the queue is available), and consumers (threads in the pool) call `take()`, which blocks when no work is available. This is how [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) is implemented (to be precise, it actually calls `offer()`, so by default doesn't block on the producer side).

Comment: 1. I don't really understand so which one is fater? using wait/notify or re-submit a task to executor service?
2. Ok, thanks you

Comment: 1. It's the same. ExecutorService uses ArrayBlockingQueue, which uses wait/notify.

Comment: I don't think it's the same, because when I re-submit a task, executor service will run it freshly (a new running instance), but if I convert the task to a "while" loop and wait, the task will run the loop again after having a notification.
Option 1: <br/>
while(true){ <br/>
doSomething();// Option 2: move to a Runnable submit to executor service again and again... <br/>
wait(); <br/>
} <br/>

Comment: and about the switching context, if the number of thread is more than the CPU core, so I think it's need to switching the context, right?

Comment: It depends on the pool size. If the pool size is fixed, the threads are already started and waiting for work. Profile it to be sure.